# Adding Espresso to instrumentTest dependency when dagger is already included in compile dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing, dagger, android-espresso

I have a gradle project (using Gradle 1.9) and I am trying to add espresso (from https://github.com/JakeWharton/double-espresso) to my project which has dagger in its compile dependencies.

Here is my dependency structure:

dependencies {

```
compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:merge:1.0.1' 
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.0' 
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+' 
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4' 
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.5.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0'

instrumentTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r2') {
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.dagger'
    exclude group:'com.google.guava', module:'guava'
}
instrumentTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso-support-v4:1.1-r2') {
    exclude group:'com.google.guava', module:'guava'
    exclude group:'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.dagger'
}
```

}

Now my problem is when I start my tests through "gradle connectedInstrumentTest" shortly after my test starts (and I see the activity getting fired), I get the following error:

...activity.MainActivityTest > testItemText[Nexus 5 - 4.4.2] FAILED 
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Errors creating object graph:
    com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.FailureHandler could not be bound with key com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.FailureHandler required by class com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.base.BaseLayerModule
:ClioAndroid:connectedInstrumentTest FAILED

When I comment out  exclude group: 'com.squareup.dagger' I get another error:
Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalAccessError' which is expected according to "http://b.android.com/65445".

I assume the problem is adding "exclude group: 'com.squareup.dagger'" messes up with daggers  object graph for espresso. I haven't been able to find a workaround for that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible your dagger library is conflicting with the espresso library? Jake updated the Dagger library to 1.2.1 a month ago.

Comment: Double Espresso is now deprecated.  Espresso 2.0 should be used instead.